# При включённых dev tools после ротейта в Google Chrome происходит обновление вкладки - как это убрать?

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-devtools

Судя по всему, с последним обновлением для Google Chrome - с включёнными devtools теперь если сделать ротейт (при выбранном девайсе, не при responsive) - вкладка перезагружается.
Кто знает, можно ли это отключить и как?